# I'm trying to create drop down lists in flask using wtforms but my form won't validate for some reason, can someone tell me why?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, wtforms

The lists look just the way I intended them to, with all the right options, but when I hit the submit('Add Movement') button, it doesn't get validated(it doesn't enter the `if form.validate_on_submit()` code block). It used to get validated before I added the SelectField so I'm inclined to think I did something wrong there.

```
@app.route('/movements', methods=['GET','POST'])
def movements():
    form = MovementForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        product = Product.query.filter_by(id=form.product.data).first()
        from_location = Location.query.filter_by(id=form.from_location.data).first()
        to_location = Location.query.filter_by(id=form.to_location.data).first()
        m = Movement(product = product.name, from_location = from_location.name, to_location = to_location.name, quantity = form.quantity.data)
        db.session.add(m)
        db.session.commit()
        movements = Movement.query.all()
        products = Product.query.all()
        locations = Location.query.all()
        return render_template('movements.html', movements=movements, products=products, locations=locations, form=form)
    
    form.product.choices = [(product.id,product.name) for product in Product.query.all()]
    form.from_location.choices = [(location.id,location.name) for location in Location.query.all()]
    form.to_location.choices = [(location.id,location.name) for location in Location.query.all()]
    movements = Movement.query.all()
    products = Product.query.all()
    locations = Location.query.all()
    return render_template('movements.html', movements=movements, products=products, locations=locations, form=form)
```

This is my model for the Movement table:

```
class Movement(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
    product = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    from_location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'))
    from_location = db.Column(db.String(50))
    to_location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'))
    to_location = db.Column(db.String(50))
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

And this is the form:

```
class MovementForm(FlaskForm):
    product = SelectField("Product", choices = [])
    from_location = SelectField("From Location", choices = [])
    to_location = SelectField("To Location", choices = [])
    quantity = StringField("Quantity", validators=[DataRequired()])
    add_movement = SubmitField("Add Movement")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have similar experience and the problem was that form wasn't validating against empty choices list. So, filling `form.from_location.choices` (and the others) before validation may solve it:

```py
@app.route('/movements', methods=['GET','POST'])
def movements():
    form = MovementForm()
    form.product.choices = [(product.id,product.name) for product in Product.query.all()]
    form.from_location.choices = [(location.id,location.name) for location in Location.query.all()]
    form.to_location.choices = [(location.id,location.name) for location in Location.query.all()]
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # your code
        
    # your code
    return render_template('movements.html', movements=movements, products=products, locations=locations, form=form)
```